# Devils path shuttle

Tags: trails

I'm planning on through hiking [Devil's Path](https://www.google.com/search?q=devil%27s%20path%20catskills&oq=devils%20path&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3j69i60j69i61.4087j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in the Catskills in November with some friends, and I'm trying to figure out the transportation. We leave about 3 hours away, so I'd prefer not to have to take two cars to leave one at each end. Some suggestions I read online thought that I we could plan on hitching a ride from one end to another, but I hate to count on that since there are 4 of us and its pretty late in the season.

I couldn't find any sort of shuttle for the path. So I'm looking into a taxi service from end to end, but that seems super costly. Does anyone know of a shuttle or an alternative I could explore?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Travelling to outdoor destination, not the Outdoors itself.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech I disagree (again).  I think that solving the logistics inherent to an outdoor trip should be on-topic on this site.

That being said, the question could be a bit more informative.  Where in the world is Devil's Path?  Somewhere in the English speaking world, presumably?  I'm sure there should be many places with this name?

Comment: This would be a better fit for Travel SE.

Comment: I created a question on meta to discuss the off-topic nature of those questions.

Comment: The reason why I chose to post the question on this site, instead of Travel SE, is because there seemed to be a much higher likely hood of getting advice from someone who has hiked the trail and directly experienced this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a good service to use for the shuttling at Devil's Path. Just in case someone else needs help, it looks like [Smiley's Transport](http://local.yahoo.com/info-11572297-smiley-s-transport-tannersville) in Tannersville, NY is a service that people use frequently. I just spoke with them on the phone and they were familiar with the trail and location. I plan to use them when I hike the trail.

**Follow Up**
We did the hike in November, and it was absolutely wonderful. Smiley's was definitely the way to go. They knew a lot about the trail and the area, and were super helpful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How much did they charge? Do they offer service from both ends of the trail?

Comment: I don't remember how much they charged, but I remember it being fair. They do service both ends. They lead us to the end of the trail where we dropped a car, then they took us to the trailhead.